# Check if a table's rows are being changed

Tags: jquery, observers

I would like to use a MutationObserver (or anything else at this point) to listen for changes in my table. My `table -> tbody -> tr` elements can be changed in various ways, such as:

1. Filtering through search (which toggles an `<tr>`-element to show or hide)
2. Filtering through checkboxes (again toggles them)
3. Removes `<tr>`-elements

By using a MutationObserver, I can go and check for changes in the table. It works when I remove an element (because the childList and subtree changes), but it does not trigger, when an element's attribute changes. Here's my observer:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    updateTable();
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#reports'), { childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true });
```

My HTML:

```
<table id="reports">
    <thead>........
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Stuff here 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Stuff here 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Stuff here 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My `updateTable()` function is pretty simple: It updates the `table -> tbody -> tr`-element backgrounds. This means, that if I check for attribute change in the observer, it will run into an endless loop, because:

> Oh someone hid the `<tr>` element! Let me go change the background. Oh look, someone changed the background! Let me change the background. Oh look! .... Endless loop

How would I go on about this? Thanks

Comment: I COULD just throw the `updateTable()` into every event I have (adding, deleting, selecting, etc), but that is so overkill.

Comment: according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver in mutation observer you can set some configuration for the mutation observer.. there is one that apparently observe target's attributes. Have you tried it ?

Comment: I menat the { attributes: true }

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Yes. If you read the last quote, you can see why that will not work out for me :(

Comment: can't you deactivate the observer in your callback and then reactivate it again ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- So after running my updateTable(); it should disable the observer? Inside the observer?

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928635/mutation-observer-dom-is-changed-by-callback-function it may not be the most efficient solution tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: It may not be a performant solution.

But what about deactivating the observer before executing the callback ? Something like

```
var observe = function(){
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
         observer.disconnect(); // stop watching changes
         updateTable(); // do your changes
         observe(); // start watching for changes again
    });
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('#reports'), { childList: true, attributes: true, subtree: true });
}
```

So the first time you would just do

```
observe();
```

when you change `#reports`, it will fire the `MutationObserver`, you disconnect it, so you can do your DOM changes, and then you would place the observer again.

Code not tested, so let me know if this works for you

Comment: Absolutely working like a charm. I added in `attributes` instead of `characterData`, as I need to check on attribute change as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great ! Sorry for not being enough clear on the comments