# Listen for table change (including hiding/showing <tr> elements)

Tags: jquery

I recently created this: [Check if a table's rows are being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567972/check-if-a-tables-rows-are-being-changed) - However, it seems like nobody knows the answer to my MutationObserver question.

I would therefore like to know if there are any possible ways, I can check whether or not a table's data has been changed. What I would essentially want is something like this:

```
$("table").on("change", function() {
    updateTable();
});
```

The `updateTable()` would then be my function, which updates the table's content correctly. What do I mean with that? Well, my function simply finds all the `<tr>` tags in the table, makes their background white, then finds all the odd `<tr>` tags and makes their background a different color.

How would I go on about this? I can do something like this (which would mean repeating myself a lot):

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    /* all my other code */
    updateTable();
});

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
    /* all my other code */
    updateTable();
});

$("#search-input").on("keyup", function() {
    /* all my search filtering code */
    updateTable();
});
```

That's a bad way of doing it. Instead what could be done, is check if the table has changed (`<table>` -> `<tbody>` -> `<tr>` if we need to be correct), however, I have been unable to do that with a MutationObserver, so I am seeking some other help.

Thanks